# Почему пропадает кнопка назад в NavigationBar?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

У меня есть несколько приложений на swift.

Переодически получаю жалобы от пользователей о том что пропадает кнопка `Назад` в `NavigationBar` и они не могут попасть на предыдущий экран.

Проблема является трудновоспроизводимой, мне удалось ее воспроизвести 2 раза на своем айфоне и оба раза случайно, при этом это было не в debug режиме, так что никаких подробностей мне это не дало.

При этом проблема не вызывает крэша, поэтому опять же минимум подробностей.

Так же есть вторая проблема. Я всегда делаю NavigationBar непрозрачным:

`controller.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false`

Но иногда это не срабатывает и NavigationBar остается прозрачным. 
Опять же я не понимаю из-за чего это происходит, но возможно эти две проблемы связаны между собой.

**Буду рад любым предположениям от чего это может происходить.**

Пример того как я работаю с UINavigationController:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        setupWindow()
        return true
    }

    func setupWindow() {
        let controller = UINavigationController()
        controller.viewControllers = [FirstViewController(), SecondViewController()]
        controller.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = controller
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

}
```

**FirstViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Firts"
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
            title: "Second",
            style: .done,
            target: self,
            action: #selector(openSecond)
        )
    }

    @objc func openSecond() {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(SecondViewController(), animated: true)
    }

}
```

**SecondViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Second"
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

p.s. Я не использую storyboard. Только код, только хардкор.

Comment: Интересный вопрос. По прозрачности - почему не appearance? `UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false`. По пропадающей - есть еще в коде что-то, что работает с navigationBar/заменой-перестановкой контроллеров. Ну и насчет дебага - можно подключить устройство с работающей программой и подключиться к процессу Вашей программы. Может чего поможет прояснить.

Answer (score 0):

Оставьте просто:

```
controller.viewControllers = [FirstViewController()]
```